# Edittext to accept Price format in android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-xml

I have an `EditText` field which used to input price.

I can add multiple decimals in it but I want to make it to accept a single decimal input, how can i achieve it? I tried `digit="0123456789."`

Comment: Do you have [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, I'm using the following `InputFilter``

```kotlin
/**
 * Definition of the CurrencyInputFilter object.
 * It allows only value from 0 to 9999.99
 */
class CurrencyInputFilter(val maxDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint: Int = 4, val maxDigitsAfterDecimalPoint: Int = 2) : InputFilter {

    override fun filter(source: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int,
                        dest: Spanned, dstart: Int, dend: Int): CharSequence? {
        val builder = StringBuilder(dest)
        builder.replace(dstart, dend, source
                .subSequence(start, end).toString())
        return if (!builder.toString().matches(("(([1-9]{1})([0-9]{0," + (maxDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint - 1) + "})?)?(\\.[0-9]{0," + maxDigitsAfterDecimalPoint + "})?").toRegex())) {
            if (source.isEmpty()) dest.subSequence(dstart, dend) else ""
        } else null
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```kotlin
// add input filter to limit price from 0 to 9999.99
priceEdit.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(CurrencyInputFilter())
```

Note: you can change the number of digits in the constructor parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` to your `EditText` view in your xml and it will work.

Also, check if the input entered is valid or not by following code

```
try {
    val number = editText.text.toString().toDouble()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.v("INVALID", "Invalid price")
}
```